# Class is not Abstract?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, overriding, abstract-class

```
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", event.getActionCommand));
        }
    }
```

This is part of my code and when I compile, I get an error saying HandlerClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method `actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener`. To my understanding, `actionPerformed` should override `HandlerClass` shouldn't it? I already tried adding "`abstract`" before the word class but then I get another error since I can't call an abstract class. I'm not sure if maybe there's an exception I can use to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you have a spelling mistake...

```
actionPerfomed
```

Should be

```
actionPerformed
           ^---- ;)
```

You may also want to use the [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation which will tell you when you're attempting to override a method that doesn't exist in the parent classes...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", event.getActionCommand));
}
```

Comment: + you might want to add @Override on the method

Comment: @OscarF - aren't you glad about the anonymity of SO.